python tika timeout header is not working sometimes
I am using tika python and i ran into a problem. tika server is running, i have both the tika-server.jar and tika-server.jar.md5, everything seems to work well until it sometimes decides that it doesn't want to work.
I have this following code:
from tika import tika
from tika import parser
parsed_text_file = parser.from_file("https://my_random_pdf.pdf", requestOptions={"timeout": 10)

If i run this code, sometimes it works perfectly fine, finishes within 20 seconds, i get my pdf and everything is good.
But there are some cases where the parser simply not finishes even tho i specified the timeout.
It just logs out this: [MainThread  ] [INFO ]  Retrieving http://my_random_pdf.pdf. and it's stuck there. Most time it was stuck it was about a full day or more (timeout was set to 3600 seconds in that case), so something is wrong.
I made some testing with the timeout, e.g.: i set the timeout to 0.1 seconds, and it worked everytime.
I also tried this: requestOptions={"timeout": 10, "headers": {"X-Tika-OCRTimeout": "10"}, but still no luck. Any suggestions where i should look or how to solve this problem?
Might be a stupid idea, but maybe an enviromental variable could solve it?
